# Django admin static files served under https

Tags: django, file, static, amazon-s3, admin

Recently i configured my Django project to work with Amazon S3. All work fine except /admin/. I cannot see any .css or image in control panel. When i inspect the code from the browser, i can see the static files url printed is something like "https://blablabla".

From https protocol i have to agree a certificate to display the requested object, so in /admin/ any of these files can't be showed. If i entered the same url but under http i can see the file without to agree anything.

How can i do to /admin/ calls the static files under http and not under https?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you should find a way to get the static files under https, not http. If you serve the admin under https but not the static files then Internet Explorer will show a warning and possibly hide the non-https content (because not everything is delivered over a secure connection).

Comment: I get them, but i have to accept a certificate in order to browser shows them. I can accept this when i enter the absolute url in browser (for example https://blbla.blabla.s3.amazonaws.com/admin/css/base.css) but when i get in http://localhost:8000/admin/ i can't accept anything so browser don't display them.

Comment: I just set up an app on Heroku with S3 for static files and the same thing happened to me. For some reason Django (or django-storages) is specifying https for the static admin files.

Comment: I'm still without solution for this issue. My control panel sucks with no js/css. Anyone knows something about this?

Comment: So, did you set `STATIC_URL='https://blah.com/'` ? And for frontend pages you can see your css/js. If yes, try change static url to `STATIC_URL='//blah.com/'`. With this browser can get needed css/js according to page protocol.

Comment: ^ This or just go to `https://localhost:8000/admin/`

Answer (score 5):

If you set:

AWS_S3_SECURE_URLS = False

in your settings.py then, all the URLS to your static files use http: instead of https:

Answer (score 1):

Please set `STATIC_URL = 'https://blbla.blabla.s3.amazonaws.com/` in `settings.py`

Comment: I agree to set this STATIC_URL to full URL with https as a prefix to make static requests work.
For other requests, please set SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER (Django), check your process manager (Gunicorn: --forwarded-allow-ips) and your proxy (nginx: proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto 'https') also.